# Win 10 volume C partition "not supported" but disk size is reduced

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I tried shrinking the C volume on my Win10 machine using Disk Management and it said that it was shrinkable by about 199GB. I chose to shrink it by 100GB, got the `request is not supported` message, but the volume ended up being apparently shrunk by 100GB. As you can see in the screenshot, the disk is now 139GB, but the Disk Management shows no unallocated space. If I try to shrink it again, it says that it is now shrinkable by 99GB.

[image: screenshot]

The reason I am doing this is to install Linux in parallel to Win10, and when I tried to boot from USB, Linux also showed no unallocated space. I have tried using the MiniTool partition wizard, but it does not show me the option to shrink/split this particular volume.

[image]

Any ideas on how do I either get back the "missing" 100GB that Windows no longer recognises or actually get those 100GB to appear as unallocated space for Linux to be installed on?

Comment: Have you restarted (not just shut down)? This may be needed before partition changes are recognised. Are you using `gparted` in Linux? What sizes does it show?

Comment: Note that `gparted` can shrink NTFS volumes, but it's always wise (if not essential) to do a full disc back-up before making any partition changes.

Comment: I have done several restarts since, no change. ``gparted`` shows the same sizes as Disk Management in Windows, with no options to shrink, as all of the volumes have a red exclamation mark next to them.

Comment: It appears like the partition table is corrupt.  It might be possible to resolve with Test Disk, but at this point, creating a backup should be a priority.

Comment: This is a brand new laptop, there is nothing on it worth backing up. The only thing stopping me from doing a full reinstall of everything is that this is a Uni laptop to which I was granted admin access. The IT support in my Uni is appalling, they want nothing to do with Linux. I am desperate to resolve this on my own if possible instead of waiting for them to deal with this for weeks to come...